# Getting double comma conflict in using mysql function GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, concatenation

I am using mysql, run a query some thing like this :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title,',') FROM `niuer_usergroups` where id IN (2,3,7,8)
```

and get the result :

```
Registered,,Author,,Administrator,,Super Users,
```

but i want the result like this :

```
Registered,Author,Administrator,Super Users
```

give me any suggestion to query gives exact result that what i want.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT separates by comma by default; try removing the second string argument inside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `GROUP_CONCAT` the wrong way. Try:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM `niuer_usergroups` 
WHERE id IN (2,3,7,8)
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

You are concatting `title` with the default separator (`,`) with a `,`. So this is what you get :D

use the keyword `SEPARATOR` to change the separator, but as you seem to want the `,`, you don't need it.

Just use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) FROM `niuer_usergroups` where id IN (2,3,7,8)
```

See for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: how is the select here any different than that displayed by the OP?  or did you mean to omit the ,','?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select group_concat(title SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM `niuer_usergroups` where id IN (2,3,7,8)
```